# Process form fields with foreach loop on posting form?

Tags: php, variables, post

I'm posting 20 results from a form, to be used on the next page, is there a quick foreach way of posting:

> $UserID1 = $_POST['UserID1'];

Where the ID changes each time rather than listing it 20 odd times? I thought a foreach statement, but i'm not too sure where to begin with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers will do the job just fine, however they introduce security issues.

Code such as:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
     $$key = $value; //Assign the value to a variable named after $key
}
```

Allows me to post any form field I wish to your page and alter any variables value, for example, say you have code something like this elsewhere:

```
if ($validation) { // Do something }
```

Then I am able to post a form field named `validation` with a value of `1` and manipulate your code as that would assign a variable called `$validation` to a value of my choosing.

Using that code to assign variables from all your `$_POST` values automatically, is the same as using `register_globals` which was deprecated due to it's blatent security issues. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

If you must do this, you must check that the posted values are something that you expect. For example, check for the existance of `UserID`. This will only allow the creation of variables if they begin with `UserID`:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (substr($key, 0, 6) == 'UserID') {
        $$key = $value; //Assign the value to a variable named after $key
    }
}
```

This will check for `$_POST['UserID1']` and create `$UserID1` and `$_POST['UserID2']` and create `$UserID2`...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`extract()`](https://www.php.net/extract):

```
extract($_POST);

echo $UserID1; // This now works
```

This is not considered a good programming practice but will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
  $$key = $value; //Assign the value to a variable named after $key
}
```

Comment: Will that use the number after UserID?

Comment: Yes. It will use what the `key` is exactly and create a variable named as the key (E.g `$UserID1`) and assign the value to it.

Comment: So if I was to add other details with the UserID, but the same number following it, would I create another foreach? For example if I wanted `$UserID1 = $_POST['UserID1']; $UserName1 = $_POST['UserName1'];`

Comment: It all happens in that single foreach. Let me explain what the double dollar sign is doing. When it goes over `$_POST['UserID1'];` $key = 'UserID1' and $value = 'whatever';. Now when we do `$$key = $value;` it looks like this expanded -> `$UserID1 = 'whatever'`

Comment: This is dangerous and should be avoided. I could use this to post any form field to your script and create any variable I choose with any value I wish.

Comment: Very true. If you do consider using this code please look at @AJReading answer to further improve it.

Comment: Thanks for this, i've tested it and it works. I see the security risk involved, but for this it's just a form that's admin side that only I will have access to anyway. I will mark AJ's post as the answer as he expanded on the more secure way but will vote yours up too. Thanks!

Comment: As a follow up to this, after having all of these items sent through to the form handling page, is it possible to create a statement that inserts each of them in to it's own row in the database? I'm assuming something like `foreach($_POST as $value) {
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Users (UserID) VALUES ('$value')");
}` would give an error as it'd be calling any posts and not splitting them up?

Comment: The `foreach` would go over each element independently and do the query for each element. So for example if your `$_POST` array looked like this: `$_POST = array('UserID1' => 'whatever', 'UserName1' => 'whatevervalue'` then the code you posted would do `INSERT INTO Users (UserID) VALUES ('whatever')");` AND `INSERT INTO Users (UserID) VALUES ('whatevervalue')");`

Comment: Ok, so if I've got the values such as $UserID1, $UserName1, $UserID2, $UserName2 is there a way using foreach to put them in to their relevant columns? I've always done things manually before, but for this task it seems logical to do it in a foreach if possible.